# AJAX and YQL doesn´t work using dreamweaver (cross-domain-request)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, cordova

I use a js to display some  content on my app (I use Dreamweaver and PhoneGap). When i preview the html separately works, but when i load the html from other page dont.

I receive this msg on the Firefox Security: ReferenceError: requestCrossDomain is not defined

This is my HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery Mobile Web App</title>
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/cross-domain-request.js"></script>


</head>
 <body>

<div id="container">

<p id="sitename"> http://catedralaltapatagonia.com/invierno/partediario.php? default_tab=0
</p>
```

```
  function codeAddress(){
  var elem = document.getElementById("sitename");
 elem.value = "http://catedralaltapatagonia.com/invierno/partediario.php?    default_tab=0";
var path =$('#sitename').val();

requestCrossDomain(path, function(results){
    $('#container').html(results);
});
return false;
};
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And my cross-domain-request.js:

```
/ JavaScript Document
// Accepts a url and a callback function to run.
function requestCrossDomain( site, callback ) {



 // Take the provided url, and add it to a YQL query. Make sure you encode it!
 var yql = 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=' +  encodeURIComponent('select * from html where url="' +  'http://catedralaltapatagonia.com/invierno/partediario.php?default_tab=0' +  '"'+' AND xpath="//*[@id=\'meteo_recuadro\']"') + '&format=xml&callback=?';






// Request that YSQL string, and run a callback function.
// Pass a defined function to prevent cache-busting.
$.getJSON( yql, function(data){

      // If we have something to work with...
if ( data.results[0] ) {
    // Strip out all script tags, for security reasons.
    // BE VERY CAREFUL. This helps, but we should do more. 
    data = data.results[0].replace(/<script[^>]*>[\s\S]*?<\/script>/gi, '');

    // If the user passed a callback, and it
    // is a function, call it, and send through the data var.
    if ( typeof callback === 'function') {
        callback(data);

    }
}
// Else, Maybe we requested a site that doesn't exist, and nothing returned.
else throw new Error('Nothing returned from getJSON.');
});
```

}

Some clue to resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I add the line

```
  <script src="js/cross-domain-request.js"></script>
```

and the js is loaded

Answer (score 1):

You appear to have an error in your external JS file, and it's not running. The final `else` statement is not correct.  Try this:

```
 / JavaScript Document
// Accepts a url and a callback function to run.
function requestCrossDomain( site, callback ) {

 // Take the provided url, and add it to a YQL query. Make sure you encode it!
 var yql = 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=' +  encodeURIComponent('select * from html where url="' +  'http://catedralaltapatagonia.com/invierno/partediario.php?default_tab=0' +  '"'+' AND xpath="//*[@id=\'meteo_recuadro\']"') + '&format=xml&callback=?';

// Request that YSQL string, and run a callback function.
// Pass a defined function to prevent cache-busting.
$.getJSON( yql, function(data){

      // If we have something to work with...
  if ( data.results[0] ) {
    // Strip out all script tags, for security reasons.
    // BE VERY CAREFUL. This helps, but we should do more. 
    data = data.results[0].replace(/<script[^>]*>[\s\S]*?<\/script>/gi, '');

    // If the user passed a callback, and it
    // is a function, call it, and send through the data var.
      if ( typeof callback === 'function') {
        callback(data);

      }
    }
    // Else, Maybe we requested a site that doesn't exist, and nothing returned.
    else {   
      throw new Error('Nothing returned from getJSON.');
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Still nothing. the html is named metereolo.html .         If I preview the meterelo.html lonely works, but when is called from the index.html....doesnt.

Comment: Have you checked the console to make sure the external file is being loaded both times?

Comment: The js is loaded when I started from the preview but not when I load the page from index

Comment: I obviously don't know your file structure, but if the JS file is not being loaded, then you have a problem.  Your console should show a network error and give the path the browser was trying to get the JS file. Maybe try this: `<script src="../js/cross-domain-request.js"></script>`.

Comment: I resolved I add <script src="js/cross-domain-request.js"></script> to my index.html. then the js is loaded

Comment: OK - yes, you need to call the script on each page where you need it.